# PHP multiple file Upload (Array) Issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I use Multiple File upload with foreach loop. But my files are not move to folder,
Here Is My Code.

```
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $file)
    {
            print_r($file);
            echo "<br>";
            $errors= array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type']; 

            echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$_FILES['image']['name'];  
            echo "<br><br>";
            $clogo = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$file);     

            //File Loading Successfully

    }
```

And Here Is an output.

[image]

Comment: `echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$_FILES['image']['name'];` you are referencing the array, not the variable that you made (`$file`)

Comment: @Darren No Luck with that. Files are not moving.

Comment: What is the result of `echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$file;` ?

Comment: Wait, `echo $baseMODULES."/upload/".$file;` ?

Comment: Please make sure you have atleast '0775' permissions for the folder to be uploaded.

Comment: @Darren yes, now its display whole path with file name but not move to  folder, is it anything wrong with my upload code ?

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($_FILES);` putting it above the loop ?

Comment: What happens if you do `foreach($_FILES['image'] as $image)` and then do `move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],$file);`. And try something like that?

Comment: @Darren Thanks for help, code work and issue solve

Comment: @ShivamPandya added answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php    
$i = 0 ;   
    foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $file)
            {
                    print_r($file);
                    echo "<br>";
                    $errors= array();
                    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
                    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$i]; 

                    echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i];  
                    echo "<br><br>";
                    $clogo = $_FILES['image']['name'][$i];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i],$file);     

                    //File Loading Successfully
               $i++;
            }
?>
```

Try this

**or**

```
<?php    
$i = 0;
    foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key=>$file)
            {
                    print_r($file);
                    echo "<br>";
                    $errors= array();
                    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
                    $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
                    $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];
                    $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'][$key]; 

                    echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$key];  
                    echo "<br><br>";
                    $clogo = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key],$file);     

                    //File Loading Successfully
               $i++;
            }
?>
```

Comment: I think sthg is wrong on `echo $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$_FILES['image']['name'][$i]; `

Answer (score 1):

You should change your foreach loop to something like this:

```
foreach($_FILES['image'] as $image) {
```

Then do the move with something like

```
move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $file);
```

As specified in the comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
$i = 0;
foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $file)
{
    $file_name = $file;
    $file_size = $_FILES['image']['size'][$i];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $file_type = $_FILES['image']['type'][$i]; 

    $file = $baseMODULES."/upload/".$file;  
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$file);     
    $i++;
}
```

?>